# Combining a small list with many tuples to create a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Currently I have a list of 6 items I want to use as a key inside a dictionary and assign each item to an individual item in a 6 tuple than throw the two into a dictionary, eg:

```
l = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
t = [(1,2,3,4,5,6),(7,8,9,10,11,12)...]
```

and I want the output to be

```
d = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,a:7,b:8,c:9,d:10,e:11,f:12....}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Dictionary does not allow duplicated keys.

Comment: Wouldn't you have a duplicate key within the same dictionary? e.g. the value of key 'a' can't be both 1 and 7.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! I realize now where I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary does not allow duplicated keys.

```
>>> {'a': 1, 'a': 7}
{'a': 7}
```

If you want to map `a` to `(1,7)`, `b` to `(2, 8)`, ...:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> t = [(1,2,3,4,5,6),(7,8,9,10,11,12)]
>>> dict(zip(l, zip(*t)))
{'a': (1, 7), 'c': (3, 9), 'b': (2, 8), 'e': (5, 11), 'd': (4, 10), 'f': (6, 12)}
```